# Why do we "pay attention"?

Tags: word-usage, word-in-context, word-meaning

I wonder, what is the etymology of **"pay attention"**? Why the word **"pay"**?

- Please, pay attention to what I am telling you.

Other versions sound logical but incorrect:

- Please, be attentive to what I am telling you.
- Please, keep your attention to what I am telling you.

However, this sound fine:

- Please, listen attentively to what I am telling you.

I guess "pay" works in the same way in other combinations, but why and how?

- Please, pay your respects to the deceased.

Comment: See [*pay attention*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/pay): "11. *verb*  
You use **pay** with some nouns, for example in the expressions **pay a visit** and **pay attention**, to indicate that something is given or done." In general, *pay* has to do with giving something. In *pay attention* you are being asked to give your attention.

Comment: **pay** enters English from Old French *paiier* during the Middle English period. It had as one of its meanings "to render that which is due" which broadens figuratively to "to fulfill a debt" and then "to fulfill an obligation"'; by the 16th c. we see "pay homage" and "pay obedience" and "pay allegiance" and "pay heed".  From "pay heed" it is but a hop and a skip to paying attention to that which demands it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you

> **pay**

you give *something*, though it is usually associated with a monetary exchange.

When someone dies, you

> **pay** your respects

to the grieving family.  So

> **pay** attention

is being asked to *give your attention* as @user3169 points out.

Comment: Agreed. Etymologically, "pay" is related to the word "please" and is used to mean "give" in certain senses that express an intention to please or to respect. Pay attention, pay wages, pay respects, pay tribute, pay homage.

Comment: Pay is used a little more broadly at times, as well, such as "to pay rope" which is to let out rope to slacken it.

Comment: @RyanHaber I believe the term is "[pay **out** rope](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pay_out)"

Comment: Oh, yes. I think you're right. :)